# Android OpenCV convertTo() from CV_32FC4 to CV_8UC4

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm just new to Android & OpenCV and currently I'm using [this](https://github.com/ikkiChung/MyRealTimeImageProcessing) project for real-time image processing. I am using the [native code cpp](https://github.com/ikkiChung/MyRealTimeImageProcessing/blob/master/JNI/ImageProcessing.cpp) from the project to implement the algorithm that I need which involves mathematical operations with float numbers applying modifications for the RGB channels for each pixel. Therefore I think it's just appropriate to use **CV_32FC4** for the first matrix. Adjustments I did in the cpp:

```
Mat mFrame(height, width, CV_32FC4, (unsigned char *)pNV21FrameData);
Mat mResult(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)poutPixels);

for(int y = 0 ; y < height ; y++){
    for(int x = 0 ; x < width ; x++){
        Vec3b BGR = mFrame.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));
        // BGR Pixel Manipulations
        mFrame.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y)) =  BGR;
    }
}

mFrame.convertTo(mResult, CV_8UC4, 1/255.0);
```

After implementing the algorithm, I'll need to convert the matrix to BGRA since it is the requirement so I'll used **CV_8UC4**. But when I run the program there is a problem with the display: [*link for actual image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez3ye.png)

[image: Output Image]

The white objects in the right side seems to be multiple instances of ruined version of what is displayed. There's nothing like that with the original code that is Canny Edge Detection so I suppose it's not a problem with my device. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: mFrame.at<Vec3b> means that each pixel of mframe is CV_8UC3 (BGR), and it is not it is 4 floats. In your example probably there should not be any harm, you read 3 bytes and you put them back... but if you change them in any way in the middle it should. use Vec4f and remember that is not BGR since you have a 4th channel !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're working on a 4 channel float matrix, so you should access it with `Vec4f`.
- You don't need to initialize the output matrix from a OpenCV function in general. So just use `Mat mResult;` and `cvtColor` will take care of creating it correctly.
- You don't need to access a pixel with `Point`, simply pass the rows and cols coordinates.

So the code becomes:

```
Mat mFrame(height, width, CV_32FC4, (unsigned char *)pNV21FrameData);

for(int y = 0 ; y < height ; y++){
    for(int x = 0 ; x < width ; x++){
        Vec4f BGRA = mFrame.at<Vec4f>(y,x);
        // BGRA Pixel Manipulations
        mFrame.at<Vec4f>(y,x) = BGRA;
    }
}

Mat mResult;
mFrame.convertTo(mResult, CV_8UC4, 1.0/255.0);
```